# libuvc_ros ERROR: cannot launch node of type [libuvc_camera/camera_node]

Tags: camera, ros, uvc

I have cloned `libuvc_ros` to my `catkin_ws/src` and do `rosmake libuvc_camera`, and I got this error:

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [libuvc_camera/camera_node]: can't locate node [camera_node] in package [libuvc_camera]

I did install `ros-kinetic-uvc-camera` and `ros-kinetic-libuvc-camera`, and I'm quite lost. Can someone please tell me what is the correct step?

Comment: Try doing `catkin_make` while in your catkin_ws folder to build the packages instead of rosmake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with ros package`uvc-camera` and referred answers from [setting a usb camera](https://answers.ros.org/question/271685/setting-a-usb-camera-in-ros/#) and [stream usb camera in ros](https://answers.ros.org/question/193121/can-anybody-please-tell-how-to-use-web-camera-in-ros/).

I checked the ros packages installed with `rospack list-names` and found `uvc-camera` is appropriate enough, then I started camera node using `rosrun uvc_camera uvc_camera_node _device:=/dev/video1`, in `rostopic list` I saw `/camera_info` and `/image_raw` which proved my solution.

Answer (score 0):

If You Don't Want To Modify libuvc_camera It's Better To Use Binaries (`ros-kinetic-uvc-camera` and `ros-kinetic-libuvc-camera`)

But  If You Want To Compile It Anyway, First Remove `ros-kinetic-uvc-camera` and `ros-kinetic-libuvc-camera` and then Be Sure To Set ROS Path To `catkin_ws/src` By Running `source <path_to_catkin>/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` (or Place It In ~/.bashrc for all terminals) and then in `catkin_ws` Run `catkin_make <-j if u want multiple job>`